# Creating an interactive publication for Android/iOS/PDF/Web

Tags: presentation-design

I have rudimentary desktop publishing experience, and I would like to create a resume (not in the publishing field!) that I can give to prospective clients as a free iOS app (iPad/iPhone), Android App, and Web Page/PDF (for those on a desktop computer).

Ideally, I would like to only have to design the content once, and 'publish' to the multiple targets - with graceful fallback (i.e. where interactivity is not possible, such as printing out the PDF, it should still make sense).

Is there a tool out there which is designed to meet this goal? I know you can probably do it with the various DPS products, but I think you need to be a bit of a wizard at it to get it all to work.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of 'interactivity' are you thinking of adding to a resume? Ideally, your resume would just be a PDF--easily viewable on most any device as-is.

Comment: Why not just a website with lots of bells and whistles?

Comment: Where'd my comment go? I commented that you should simply use an epub format.

Answer (score 2):

[Parse](https://www.parse.com/) and [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) come to mind.

To be honest, though, I don't know if an app that is all about you is the best use of your time. While I understand that you'd want to show off your programming moxie, I don't think I'd want to have to download your app and have that sitting in my list of apps to get info about you when I can just open a web page for anyone else. It's a lot of work for a questionable return.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - I might have been a bit misleading when I said I wanted to provide it as an App - I don't mean programming something myself, more, using a publication framework to *generate* an IPA or APK from an interactive document (such as an epub).

What would be IDEAL, would be a MS Word style authoring environment, that was capable of doing a bit of interactivity (simple animation, expanding regions etc), which 'saves to' IPA/APK/PDF etc etc...

Comment: I've used Sencha, and the devices compatibility is great. You can export your 'app' to any of those formats you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I commend you for this but you realize making each independent Apple App, Android App and Web PDF would be very time consuming?  Also if I recall IOS apps require you to pay a membership to Apple to publish and the framework is only offered to mac users?

I do see you mention publish but why not learn how to create a digital book in this case learn how to create an **epub**.  You can submit free to Apple as long as your epub is free (you would use your Apple Safari Login with no fees), you don't need an ISBN to submit **IF** your epub is free.  Android devices can view epubs, and an epub is a step up from a PDF.  Either option is a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Our Desktop Publisher actually does just what you're after and it's all free if you're just after converting a few pages. It takes a PDF and exports it as EPUB, HTML5, PhoneGap. We actually convert text and fonts to real text and fonts, not any cheap bitmapping cheats. Have a look here

http://flowpaper.com

Disclaimer: I work for Devaldi which manages this product

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to suggest Maglr ([www.maglr.com](https://www.maglr.com)). We provide two solutions:

1. Start with a responsive interactive publication (readable on multiple screensizes). You can choose from 50 templates. When ready the result is also available as printable A4 PDF.
2. For the professional designer we provide the Pro editor. You can create and publish whatever you like. With Pro you can design and animate the pages according your own insights, without any restrictions. The design can be separately arranged for desktop, mobile and print from the same source material..

I also have to say, Maglr is a product we are using daily, but also developed ourselves.